# CKEditor not displaying data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor plugin in CakePHP like this :

```
$this->element('ckeditor', array(
       'name' => 'body', 
       'description'=>$body,
       'id' => 'description', 
       'width' => 628, 
       'height' => 250
));
```

But I am unable to see the content on page load. 
$instructionDetails['Instruction']['body'] contains html data. I tried static data also and its displaying in it but not html data. 
On changing language I am able to see the content since I am using:

CKEDITOR.instances.description.setData(data);

in the JavaScript change event. Is there way to use `setData` in `$this->element('ckeditor')` with other params?

Comment: show what html this code created. also your complete code of javascript

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `ckeditor` to open in which default mode. The mode to load at the editor startup depends on the plugins loaded. By default, the "wysiwyg" and "source" modes are available.

**Use This**

`CKEDITOR.config.startupMode = 'source'`

`CKEDITOR.instances.config.startupMode = 'source'`

What it will is open the data as source to you.